# Flex barchart datatips way too dark

Tags: apache-flex, bar-chart

How can I customize my barchart datatips in flex? The transparent background of them is too dark to see any of the text in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your chart, there's a property called `dataTipRenderer` where you can create your own custom datatip.  [Look here for more information](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c28.html).